# how to offset grid in javascript Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have grid on a canvas that is running Conway's game of life. But there is a problem when the cells from the game reach the edges in that they cant spread any longer and you can see them just stop. So i was wondering if it is possible to offset the whole grid på 10 cells so that the red lines are not showing. So as to hide the cells hitting the edge.

[image: enter GridImage]

Here is the code for the grid

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var cellSize = 16;
var gridColor = "#4a4a4a";


//set canvas resolution to screen resolution
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


var cellsInRow = parseInt(ctx.canvas.height/cellSize)+20;
var cellsInCollum = parseInt(ctx.canvas.width/cellSize)+20;

//create array
let arry = [];



for(var i = 0; i < cellsInRow; i++){
    
    arry[i] = [];
    
    for(var j = 0; j < cellsInCollum; j++){
        
        arry[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

let arryOld = arry.map(row => [...row]);



//draw on canvas
setInterval(drawCells, 1);
canvasBackground();
canvasGrid();



function getCursonPointer(canvas, event){
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
    
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
    
    setCell(x, y);
    
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    
    getCursonPointer(canvas, e);                        
});


//set cell in array
function setCell(x, y){
    
    for(var i = 0; i < cellsInRow; i++){
        
        for(var j = 0; j < cellsInCollum; j++){
        
            if((y >= (i*cellSize) && y <= ((i*cellSize)+cellSize-1)) &&(x >= (j*cellSize) && x <= ((j*cellSize)+cellSize-1))){
                if(arry[i][j] == 0){
                    arry[i][j] = 1;  
                }else{
                    arry[i][j] = 0;  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


function drawCells(){
     for(var i = 0; i < cellsInRow; i++){
        
        for(var j = 0; j < cellsInCollum; j++){
            
            if(arry[i][j] == 1){
                ctx.clearRect(j * cellSize+1, i * cellSize+1, cellSize-2, cellSize-2);
                
                ctx.fillStyle = "white";
                ctx.font = "8px Arial";
                ctx.fillText(i, j*cellSize + 4, i*cellSize + (cellSize/2));

            }else{
                ctx.fillStyle ="black";
                ctx.fillRect(j * cellSize+1, i * cellSize+1, cellSize-2, cellSize-2); 
            }
        }
    }
}

//draw background
function canvasBackground(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

//draw the grid
function canvasGrid(){
    for(var i = 0; i < cellsInRow; i++){

        if(i == 10 || i == cellsInRow-10){
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";   
        }
        else if(i%10 == 0){
            ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
        }else{
            ctx.strokeStyle = gridColor;   
        }
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, i*cellSize);
        ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, i*cellSize);
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.stroke();
        
        for(var j = 0; j < cellsInCollum; j++){
            
            if(j == 10 || j == cellsInCollum-10){
               ctx.strokeStyle = "red";  
            }
            else if(j%10 == 0){
                ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
            }else{
                ctx.strokeStyle = gridColor;   
            }
            
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(j*cellSize, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(j*cellSize, canvas.height);
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
}
```

keep in mind that I want the array to also be offset by the same amount so the upper right corner(under and left of the red lines) would still be arry[10][10].

In the image the black is the canvas and the green is the screen. I basicly want to shift the canvas and grid so that grid position [10][10] is in the corner of the screen. the red lines intersecting is the [10][10] position
[image: canvas]

Comment: I suggest that you get a piece of paper and draw what you want it to look like. Or you can use a tool like MS Paint to make a digital version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're looking for, but if you want a perfect grid that doesn't overflow you can try this.

```
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth - (window.innerWidth % cellSize * 10 );
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight - (window.innerHeight % cellSize * 10);

var cellsInRow = ctx.canvas.height / cellSize; 
var cellsInCollum = ctx.canvas.width / cellSize;
```

You are ignoring that extra `width` and `height` of **window** that can have a partial grid that is not perfect 10 * 10